# Speed up re.sub() on large strings representing large files in python?

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am running this python code to reduce multi-line patterns to singletons however, I am doing this on extremely large files of 200,000+ lines.

Here is my current code:

```
import sys
import re

with open('largefile.txt', 'r+') as file:
    string = file.read()
    string = re.sub(r"((?:^.*\n)+)(?=\1)", "", string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(string)
    file.truncate()
```

The problem is the re.sub() is taking ages (10m+) on my large files. Is it possible to speed this up in any way?

Example input file:

```
hello
mister
hello
mister
goomba
bananas
goomba
bananas
chocolate
hello
mister
```

Example output:

```
hello
mister
goomba
bananas
chocolate
hello
mister
```

These patterns can be bigger than 2 lines as well.

Comment: Your regular expression and the `*` and `+` in it match a huge number of combinations that all have to be taken into a count. You will have to find smarter solution.

Comment: You could try processing the file in parallel with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regexps are compact here, but will never be speedy. For one reason, you have an inherently line-based problem, but regexps are inherently character-based. The regexp engine has to deduce, over & over & over again, where "lines" are by searching for newline characters, one at a time. For a more fundamental reason, everything here is brute-force character-at-a-time search, remembering nothing from one phase to the next.

So here's an alternative. Split the giant string into a list of lines, just once at the start. Then that work never needs to be done again. And then build a dict, mapping a line to a list of the indices at which that line appears. That takes linear time. Then, given a line, we don't have to search for it at all: the list of indices tells us at once every place it appears.

Worse-case time *can* still be poor, but I expect it will be at least a hundred times faster on "typical" inputs.

```py
def dedup(s):
    from collections import defaultdict

    lines = s.splitlines(keepends=True)
    line2ix = defaultdict(list)
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        line2ix[line].append(i)
    out = []
    n = len(lines)
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        line = lines[i]
        # Look for longest adjacent match between i:j and j:j+(j-i).
        # j must be > i, and j+(j-i) <= n so that j <= (n+i)/2.
        maxj = (n + i) // 2
        searching = True
        for j in reversed(line2ix[line]):
            if j > maxj:
                continue
            if j <= i:
                break
            # Lines at i and j match.
            if all(lines[i + k] == lines[j + k]
                   for k in range(1, j - i)):
                searching = False
                break
        if searching:
            out.append(line)
            i += 1
        else: # skip the repeated block at i:j
            i = j
    return "".join(out)
```

### EDIT

This incorporates Kelly's idea of incrementally updating `line2ix` using a `deque` so that the candidates looked at are always in `range(i+1, maxj+1)`. Then the innermost loop doesn't need to check for those conditions.

It's a mixed bag, losing a little when there are very few duplicates, because in such cases the `line2ix` sequences are very short (or even singletons for unique lines).

Here's timing for a case where it really pays off: a file containing about 30,000 lines of Python code. Many lines are unique, but a few kinds of lines are very common (for example, the empty `"\n"` line). Cutting the work in the innermost loop can pay for those common lines. `dedup_nuts` was picked for the name because this level of micro-optimization is, well, nuts ;-)

```
71.67997950001154 dedup_original
48.948923900024965 dedup_blhsing
2.204853900009766 dedup_Tim
9.623824400012381 dedup_Kelly
1.0341253000078723 dedup_blhsingTimKelly
0.8434303000103682 dedup_nuts
```

And the code:

```py
def dedup_nuts(s):
    from array import array
    from collections import deque

    encode = {}
    decode = []
    lines = array('L')
    for line in s.splitlines(keepends=True):
        if (code := encode.get(line)) is None:
            code = encode[line] = len(encode)
            decode.append(line)
        lines.append(code)
    del encode
    line2ix = [deque() for line in lines]
    view = memoryview(lines)
    out = []
    n = len(lines)
    i = 0
    last_maxj = -1
    while i < n:
        maxj = (n + i) // 2
        for j in range(last_maxj + 1, maxj + 1):
            line2ix[lines[j]].appendleft(j)
        last_maxj = maxj
        line = lines[i]
        js = line2ix[line]
        assert js[-1] == i, (i, n, js)
        js.pop()
        for j in js:
            #assert i < j <= maxj
            if view[i : j] == view[j : j + j - i]:
                for k in range(i + 1, j):
                    js = line2ix[lines[k]]
                    assert js[-1] == k, (i, k, js)
                    js.pop()
                i = j
                break
        else:
            out.append(line)
            i += 1
    #assert all(not d for d in line2ix)
    return "".join(map(decode.__getitem__, out))
```

Some key invariants are checked by asserts there, but the expensive ones are commented out for speed. Season to taste.

Comment: *"inherently line-based problem, but regexps are inherently character-based"* - Solution: temporarily encode each line as one character... No problem with only 200,000 lines :-)

Comment: What I find even more nuts is that you have a file with 30,000 lines of Python code :-). Or is it generated, and that contributes to it having a few very common kinds of lines?

Comment: It's been growing for years. Whenever I start a little project, I begin by adding an `if 1:` block at the end. For example, all the code in _this_ issue is nested under the final such block now. When the project is over, I change it to `if 0:`. So the code is never thrown away. A plain newline accounts for about 10% of the lines. 2nd-most common is `if 0:\n` :-) You might guess that things like `else:` are very common too, and they are, but in the context of the current problem a match requires that they're indented the same. From one block to the next, the code has little in common.

Answer (score 2):

@TimPeters' line-based comparison approach is good but wastes time in repeated comparisons of the same lines. @KellyBundy's encoding idea is good but wastes time in the overhead of a regex engine and text encoding.

A more efficient approach would be to adopt @KellyBundy's encoding idea in @TimPeters' algorithm, but instead of encoding lines into characters, encode them into an `array.array` of 32-bit integers to avoid the overhead of text encoding, and then use a `memoryview` of the `array` for quick slice-based comparisons:

```
from array import array

def dedup_blhsingTimKelly2(s):
    encode = {}
    decode = []
    lines = s.splitlines(keepends=True)
    n = len(lines)
    for line in lines:
        if line not in encode:
            encode[line] = len(decode)
            decode.append(line)
    lines = array('L', map(encode.get, lines))
    del encode
    line2ix = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        line2ix[line].append(i)
    view = memoryview(lines)
    out = []
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        line = lines[i]
        maxj = (n + i) // 2
        searching = True
        for j in reversed(line2ix[line]):
            if j > maxj:
                continue
            if j <= i:
                break
            if view[i: j] == view[j: j + j - i]:
                searching = False
                break
        if searching:
            out.append(decode[line])
            i += 1
        else:
            i = j
    return "".join(out)
```

A run of @KellyBundy's benchmark code with this approach added, originally named `dedup_blhsingTimKelly`, now amended with Tim and Kelly's comments and named `dedup_blhsingTimKelly2`:

```
2.6650364249944687 dedup_original
1.3109814710041974 dedup_blhsing
0.5598453340062406 dedup_Tim
0.9783012029947713 dedup_Kelly
0.24442325498966966 dedup_blhsingTimKelly
0.21991234300367068 dedup_blhsingTimKelly2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3Vffb9s2EH7XX0G4DyZrVbFdFCiEqn3agGLZXpo9OZ5BS2ebMkUKIt0k2Pa3Z0dStqXESYomGNAGCOI7Hr/7@V3M@sZutHr7vm5ub0VV68aSBqL9J64KXe0lYxuh1tGq0RWxogJhSXsSpHDCm4bf7A@8EPS5lhJyK7Qy@9MCVnwnbSFyG0UB3ZCMzIbDpNRCUfo6BJDkGy1yMDTYJNzkQiwkWAuNick2m4xZTIaXasgYWemGLIhQLvg10HdjNo8c6h70JKRHeTcejxmLIgwLQyt29UI3Yi0Ul9SwNCL404DdNQgNidktaTOg9FP6V/L6UrERo5@yywkbxGSAvwi4knxtMjT9/c/zi8/nn//4pYe9lBuDnh@GDrgPo5J/nPGXHuiFqA6AUihwiZvE1FJYL9ItQA2qMNlFswN2sJuKa7Ts9INKYWw4dwUVsTdzZQW1q6DhFqhHbJ11gGbu7zzhtXNERQDRO@s6O/eCwo8SVAvgVQJVY//paiMkOiIfiOpDu0vuwkzMD/pX5FzrrQ9Ramy3wZErSp6DsqTiNt@QJdgrAEVEWhLsPCnTckTLN4IlHZCSVDu8ugTy0aXq7YIV@ZBhuEYTu@EW7VCkaiTY2fR4v@LXJXF6MiJ44@yMTA9nBniTb7DPaOBKfjhwIZd@TOErTjEUtFe@Tll9eVZo/NF76h@4n1wrK1QH@3ADoxX37ZcN8G1Pi2X0w4IpipB9qF5yF5JLSdsmYLLbOcn2TSm9fM9Xm@n2SMhJjOhvsFDsfmTdav3KpYEnYseIDlf6aDhv@wl08bF@ImSUkclBBegoxRqYraixz4AtqQEHvCBLqfOtr0pa3kHISNml7WAQtgv6PcVy5OVvIOXN9MBOULku3Ez//a@XC2jlliPfyt4TXPJsaNnq1Wm3YP5EaRu47Jz2Kxd0YQpb7BBbv4ZBd7/G@7j95qfD82GMo1TTgJqswYZNYhhr05atxzu7aDab313lis1fbiF9FXCFbiqodHPjhG4Fe9vqO1fTj78V0NgVZiZSUnqme6lECVPyHJ7/TxQOw9bW4EkqvwhTnyZqK38rUZ/HyrylYjhjjzE2P8HTWT5vZ/R7SPooV37krw8/EUcxg0mfp63mZ@TqsxhK/UPhhTiZbxra4eVzidl9qDzGSGd3fCkkjzw@vrBuQV3qR/T2f7hHd8jRaqdy45ncff3E/Q0ZH98acbcf8elF@oB6GsF1je9B9Oa9zsZzbGjkOrJyBQ/KSdqObY2vNEtXaOIGPFx1Afe/IbxtJ6KPcuya8xbeqlTyalnwlDjImOBSWkKTTY79Cw6xMKtksVC8gsWCdSJht7f/AQ)

Comment: It could maybe be further optimized by not having a static `line2ix`. For small `i`, large `j` will repeatedly fall into the `j > maxj` case and take time for actively ignoring them. You could instead extend `line2ix` during the process as needed. Similarly, each passed index could be removed from `line2ix` (so use a `deque`?), allowing to remove the `j <= i` check. Then again... this solution is already so much more complex than what was originally a oneliner :-)

Comment: More depends on characteristics of the OP's data, which we don't know. We know one thing: for inputs of about 200,000 lines, it took about 10 minutes. I haven't yet been able to contrive any kind of data that runs so _fast_ with the original, unless there are _very_ long repeated blocks. In general, this is an instance of the "tandem repeats" problem, about which there's a large literature. Very sophisticated approaches based on suffix trees have excellent worst-case time.

Comment: @TimPeters The "+" in "10m+" might indicate that it took longer than 10 minutes and that they killed it at that point.

Comment: @KellyBundy, the incrementally-updated `deque` idea helps if there are a great many duplicate lines but few repeated blocks. And the more extreme that gets, the more your original code wins the speed contest (against everything else!). If there are few duplicated lines, the `deque` idea hurts a little (scant payback for the added complication).

Answer (score 1):

Nesting a quantifier within a quantifier is expensive and in this case unnecessary.

You can use the following regex without nesting instead:

```
string = re.sub(r"(^.*\n)(?=\1)", "", string, flags=re.M | re.S)
```

In the following test it more than cuts the time in half compared to your approach:

https://replit.com/@blhsing/HugeTrivialExperiment

Answer (score 1):

Another idea: You're talking about "200,000+ lines", so we can encode each unique line as one of the 1,114,112 possible characters and simplify the regex to `r"(.+)(?=\1)"`. And after the deduplication, decode the characters back to lines.

```
def dedup(s):
    encode = {}
    decode = {}
    lines = s.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        if line not in encode:
            c = chr(len(encode))
            encode[line] = c
            decode[c] = line
    s = ''.join(map(encode.get, lines))
    s = re.sub(r"(.+)(?=\1)", "", s, flags=re.S)
    return '\n'.join(map(decode.get, s))
```

A little benchmark based on blhsing's but with some repeating lines (times in seconds):

```
2.5934535119995417 dedup_original
1.2498892020012136 dedup_blhsing
0.5043159520009795 dedup_Tim
0.9235864399997809 dedup_Kelly
```

I built a pool of 50 lines of 10 random letters, then joined 5000 random lines from that pool.

The two fastest with 10,000 lines instead:

```
2.0905018440007552 dedup_Tim
3.220036650000111 dedup_Kelly
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXBjts2EL3rKwbuYclY0dobBAiMKDklQNBtL9mevI5BSyObMkUKItVskPbbt0PSlqXdJhFgWOS8eTN8nBm139zB6Fdv2u7xUTat6Rx0mJzfhC5Nc15Z10m9T6rONOBkg9LByRJXSRIRFnJYX11ltZGasReRJCsORhZoWcRkwhZSbhU6h51N4ZgvFzyFq3t9xTlUpoMtSO0T2CN7veCbxLOeSf@XMrC8XiwWnCdJiRWUWPbt1nRyL7VQzPJVAvR06PqOqDGz/Y51M8ber75kL@41n3P2Pr9f8lkKM/oRYaXE3uYE/eOv27tPt5/@/DDh3qmDpcg/po68P2aFfzz484T0TjYDYdC6MEph4aTR9iw4oUWvXCkLUt0DldToFbKZbZV0YcmOiC3q0uZ3XY98wN3IB0KOKJiS1kW7V16mAeb1R9032AmHLDCeshoRrf3/JhOtD8RkJDG98yWwCQtNrwr1iSBsSdpahLevB6koELwFPaX2Tt5hLTfD/m9wa8wxpKgM1YV1IMpaFKgdNMIVB9ih@4qoQa5qoBKBelXPWf1S8mxEUkPTk@sO4Z0/asBFFLzNKV1rwB2EIxwtmZ5Lfn1z8W/EQw1@H@ZAHtfXcDPYLIquOFBBEMBLPhh8ynWoZ/ybyh1LNpFvJGuQpyLwuxBpavBPYbSTesQ9eFC28jl@16E4TnZJxlAsdEQZTx/Vy55SCqXY6RLosMcN5OdLqcP6WazTSY@Xzl2mxP6ShOLPMxur9VEoi7/InTIaXKZsVG/nCvT58elBYJ7DcthCCrQiDexRtnTPSFfSIhV4CTtlimNQZVU/YcihHvf3bBbHEMWddO7vqNS3oXdRF6b0hfz937Aucbp@0rIszL6hCc8dGFCrsQjBoo2L/ek5p2oUxFkcOuabLtr5VJG4GUvPYyfGmOW62Jw6MBjHs7cR7Yk226OLo8KeInjcZfhlP5mnn/lYUH/0C3tMIbJ75qTqdWHDyBoP9HQ6hNPL@EzH95HgQ0vTk9wDzXqxoRtKvMSVVzBuLlebKGJLXxLHKoL4ao@uPoPpB@nVeTxPWC7X4KPFbyJTotmVYgWeMgUapzvs8uXlQmJAOmmVbbdaNLjd8lEm/PHxPw)):

```
import re
import random
import string
from timeit import timeit

strings = [''.join((*random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=10), '\n')) for _ in range(50)]
s = ''.join(random.choices(strings, k=5000))

def dedup_original(s):
    return re.sub(r"((?:^.*\n)+)(?=\1)", "", s, flags=re.MULTILINE)

def dedup_blhsing(s):
    return re.sub(r"(^.*\n)(?=\1)", "", s, flags=re.M | re.S)

def dedup_Tim(s):
    from collections import defaultdict

    lines = s.splitlines(keepends=True)
    line2ix = defaultdict(list)
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        line2ix[line].append(i)
    out = []
    n = len(lines)
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        line = lines[i]
        # Look for longest adjacent match between i:j and j:j+(j-i).
        # j must be > i, and j+(j-i) <= n so that j <= (n+i)/2.
        maxj = (n + i) // 2
        searching = True
        for j in reversed(line2ix[line]):
            if j > maxj:
                continue
            if j <= i:
                break
            # Lines at i and j match.
            if all(lines[i + k] == lines[j + k]
                   for k in range(1, j - i)):
                searching = False
                break
        if searching:
            out.append(line)
            i += 1
        else: # skip the repeated block at i:j
            i = j
    return "".join(out)

def dedup_Kelly(s):
    encode = {}
    decode = {}
    lines = s.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        if line not in encode:
            c = chr(len(encode))
            encode[line] = c
            decode[c] = line
    s = ''.join(map(encode.get, lines))
    s = re.sub(r"(.+)(?=\1)", "", s, flags=re.S)
    return '\n'.join(map(decode.get, s))

funcs = dedup_original, dedup_blhsing, dedup_Tim, dedup_Kelly
expect = funcs[0](s)
for f in funcs[1:]:
    print(f(s) == expect)

for _ in range(3):
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(s), number=1)
        print(t, f.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: FYI, picking 200,000 strings from a universe of 5,000 50-character strings, my version took about 2 seconds compared to yours at over 300 seconds (the originals are too slow to endure). The `line2ix` dict in mine can save an enormous amount of useless searching, which depends mostly on the number of lines total (using any flavor of regexp encoding can't "skip over" any useless match attempts).

Comment: Thanks for testing. I'm pretty much limited to TIO and 60 seconds at the moment. Yeah, very much depends on the size of that universe. You increased it by factor 100, and our time ratio increased by a factor of ~100 accordingly. Would be good to know what their actual data is like. Maybe they can test all solutions and tell us their times. I do suspect yours will win by far. I had thought of doing something like that as well, but the uncertainty about their data kept me from pursuing it. Then I was just curious about this hack's speed, rather disappointed it seems barely faster than blhsing's.

Comment: Ya, there's no way we can guess. My approach is hoping that there aren't a great many duplicate lines, so that `len(line2ix[line])` is typically small. That's where it can win big-time.